# making a 70 kg fit body with proper muscle toning

Tags: gym, food, bodyweight, yoga

Myself 21 years old male. I used to weigh 76 kg (height - 174 cm which is still same) earlier 3 or 4 months ago.

As a matter of weight reduction and muscle toning(specially chest and abs)...I started doing some physical activities daily which included

```
      1.  abs streching sideways and backwards.
      2.  Simply doing 100 + 80 + 70 jumps..(total 250)
      3.  Abs Crunches
      4.  push ups ( 15 x 2 normal , 10 x 2 leg raised , 8 x 2 placing fists)
      5.  Chin Ups (4 sets)(max 3 per set)
```

Now. What i have observed **i have lost weight to 65 kg and have just become lean and i couldn't see better results in other aspects(perfect shaping or toning within body) other than just weight loss.**
I used to eat heavily during break fast , medium lunch and much less dinner. I avoided carb foods to greater extent.

**Now I m planning to go to a gym (targeting abs , arms and chest) at evening and performing basic yoga at morning including simple activities like meditation , pranayama etc**. My main goal is to make a ***70 kg fit body with pretty much muscle toning, endurance and flexiblity.*** Not the massive one we see in wrestlers.

So Here are my following doubts

```
       1. Should I Eat much more and workout to make my body weight reach 70 kg or Should I rely on minimum weights workout at gym with proper resting waiting for my muscles  to grow since i have heard muscles growth leads to weight gain ?
       2. Is it good to include yoga during morning along with gym at evening as i've mentioned earlier ?
       3. Is der anything i have to consider as i've been doing certain physical activites daily as i've told earlier ?
```

*Please Also feel free to suggest your own ideas by which i can achieve my target from my current condition*

Answer (score 2):

First of all, info on your current body fat percentage would be usefull, but I can give you some pointers even without it.

You were doing mostly cardio/high reps. While this could be usefull for weight loss, youre saying you already are lean. If so, you should be doing strength training. If you need to lose some more fat, it will help you doing so without losing muscle.

A big part of looking toned, besides low BF%, is having muscles. Strength trainign will help in that respect too. The difference in gaining muscle/losing fat while strength training lays in your diet. While manipulating your calorie intake, you can achieve different goals. Still, keep in mind to have at least 1-2g of protein per 1kg of bodyweight daily.

**DONT** do what you intended that is "targeting abs , arms and chest". You should do all the big muscle groups (back, chest, legs) to ensure proper body composition, and you should be doing compound movements - they will give the smaller muscles proper workout as a side effect (like arms or abs). Check out the "friends dont let friends skip leg day" internet memes to find out why doing whole body is important.

The question youre asking has been asked a lot over here. I hope my answer will point you in the right direction in terms of what to search for. Determine what you need to achieve the desired looks, search the site for question on proper diet and training plans that help with getting there.

Comment: i don't think i can maintain throughout all my muscles even though i do normal squats without any equipments.......but the basic doubt i have should i eat more targeting 70 kg or should i eat normally with around proper protein intake waiting for my muscles to grow after every workout. I didn't understand the following statement u said `Still, keep in mind to have at least 1-2g of protein per 1kg of bodyweight daily.`

Comment: And Do u really think doing yoga and workout on alternate days is a good thing since while my muscles takes rest every next day , I can make my inner body and mind healthy by doing yoga at that time i.e monday - yoga , tuesday  - cardio + workout etc.....I m sorry i m asking too much. But in internet almost all fitness blogs discuss about making a lean body massive gym or the other. I just want to halt my weight at 70 kg with proper endurance , toning and flexiblity.....

Comment: You seem to be scared of getting too big. You wont. getting really big is a LOT of hard work and a very specific diet. You are also fully able to do all your bug muscle groups. Just do some pull ups, bench presses, overhead presses and squats, maybe some deadlifts.This training hits all the groups. I meant that if you want to weight 70kg you should eat at least 70-140g of protein a day. And for the training, as far as i know, yoga is mostly stretching, so it should be fine. You are in fact asking a lot of questions and you should break them up into separate ones. Also, please search the site.